# How to locate and clean /dev/nvme0n1p2?

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem

When I execute `df -H` I get:

`/dev/nvme0n1p2   63G   42G   18G  70% /`

I'd like to clean this partition as it has 70% used space, but how do I locate it? Where are the files?

If I do disc space check with `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h`, I get

```
0   /proc
0   /sys
4.0K    /cdrom
4.0K    /dev
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /media
8.0K    /mnt
16K /lost+found
768K    /tmp
3.0M    /run
14M /etc
180M    /root
561M    /boot
5.6G    /opt
8.1G    /snap
13G /var
21G /usr
176G    /home
222G    /
```

This means the `/` takes up 222 GB, but the above partition at `/` only 42?

Comment: It seems you have another disk for the `/home` directory. Most data on `/` is in `/var` and `usr`. Try running the same command in these directories, maybe with `--max-depth=2` to find out where the data is located.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Running `docker system prune` reduced usage to 70% from 100% for me but I am trying to get this even lower.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `/` is the root of the system. Everything else is mounted on subdirectories of `/`. You can see this more clearly if you look at the output of `mount` or `lsblk`. For example, on my system:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   186G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  1000M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  56.6G  0 part  /
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0 680.1G  0 part  
│ └─home    254:0    0 680.1G  0 crypt /home
└─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0    30G  0 part  [SWAP]
```

This tells me that the partition `nvme0n1p5` is mounted at `/` and the partition `nvme0n1p6` is mounted on `/home`, a subdirectory of `/`.

When you do `du /`, that will search through `/` *and any subdirectories, even if they are on a different file system*. This is why you see 222 GB: you are also checking other partitions in addition to `nvme0n1p2` because they are presumably mounted somewhere under `/`. Most likely your `/home` is on a different partition, as is the case on my system, since your `/home` is reported at 176G and 222G - 176G = 46G, which agrees with the output of `df`.

To see only the usage of `/` and nothing else, you need the `-x` flag. From `man du`:

```
  -x, --one-file-system
          skip directories on different file systems
```

Again, using my system as an example, your original command gives me:

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h
0   /proc
0   /sys
12K /srv
16K /lost+found
2.1M    /run
23M /tmp
27M /etc
54M /dev
71M /boot.old
72M /boot
315M    /root
2.1G    /opt
20G /var
21G /usr
228G    /home
270G    /
```

But if I add `-x`, I get the expected output:

```
$ sudo du -xh --max-depth=1 / | sort -h
12K /srv
16K /lost+found
27M /etc
71M /boot.old
72M /boot
315M    /root
2.1G    /opt
20G /var
21G /usr
43G /
```