# How to clean /dev/nvme0n1p3/?

Tags: 22.04, disk-usage, df, du

My Ubuntu 22 is showing full disk used.
See that `/dev/nvme0n1p3  875G  824G  6.9G 100% /`?
But how do I `cd` into that?
Due to this disk being full, my server is affected, several services have stopped due to `no space left on device`.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.4G   12G  11% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3  875G  824G  6.9G 100% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop1       74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/864
/dev/loop2       67M   67M     0 100% /snap/cups/1024
/dev/loop3       75M   75M     0 100% /snap/core22/1033
/dev/loop4      159M  159M     0 100% /snap/chromium/2734
/dev/loop5       67M   67M     0 100% /snap/cups/980
/dev/nvme0n1p2  488M   84M  380M  19% /boot
/dev/loop7      497M  497M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
/dev/loop8       41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20671
/dev/loop9       41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20290
/dev/loop10      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
/dev/loop11     160M  160M     0 100% /snap/chromium/2738
```

I have been banging my head against wall to find where those files are? where I can find and delete them?

Cannot find it using this command.

```
du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h
du: cannot access '/proc/2216465': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2216468/task/2216468/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2216468/task/2216468/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2216468/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/2216468/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       /dev
0       /proc
0       /sys
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /media
16K     /lost+found
580K    /tmp
5.8M    /etc
83M     /boot
914M    /root
1.4G    /run
1.8G    /home
3.0G    /opt
3.4G    /snap
4.6G    /usr
9.0G    /var
24G     /
```

Not even this

```
sudo du -xh --max-depth=1 / | sort -h
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /media
16K     /lost+found
40K     /snap
588K    /tmp
5.8M    /etc
914M    /root
1.8G    /home
3.0G    /opt
4.6G    /usr
9.0G    /var
20G     /
```

Not even this

```
df -h --output=source,target | awk 'NR>1 {print $2}' | xargs -I {} du -h --max-depth=1 {} 2>/dev/null | sort -rh | head -n 10
24G     /
9.1G    /var
4.6G    /usr
3.4G    /snap
3.0G    /opt
1.8G    /home
1.4G    /run/log
1.4G    /run
1.4G    /run
1.3G    /snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr
```

`sudo ncdu -x /` output

[image]

How do I find largest directories/files and free up space?

I know there is similar question asked [How to locate and clean /dev/nvme0n1p2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435058/how-to-locate-and-clean-dev-nvme0n1p2)

But even running commands from the answers, I cannot find directories/files taking up all of space.

Comment: If installing and running `ncdu` doesn't show anything, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1500837/1004020

Comment: tldr of the linked answer: `sudo lsof | grep deleted` and kill the problematic process or reboot

Comment: @DanielT lsof  was not installed, when I tried to install I got `You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`. Rebooting server simply resolved issue, all disk is freed up now. Do you have any idea what steps should be taken to avoid this issue?

Comment: It just means one of your processes had a temporary file open. Linux processes can delete files and keep reading/writing to them. You would need to wait until this happens again, then determine which service on your server has a bug of allowing this to happen. Then you should either report the bug or restart the broken service every once in a while.

Comment: @DanielT but it will remain mystery what program was keeping that file open :(

Comment: If you really want to find out ***now***, you can boot into a LiveCD and run data recovery software. Since the big file covers most of your disk, you could also just pick 10 random locations on your disk to read from, and see if it resembles something familiar that indicates a particular program.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielT

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because my answer from the link is already in that question. You're welcome. Feel free to upvote the linked question and answer instead of thanking me here